# Change the geolocation error message in flutter inappwebview package

Tags: flutter, webview, flutter-inappwebview

```
"""
class _WebviewState extends State<Webview> {
  Future<void> getPermission() async {
    Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
      Permission.locationWhenInUse,
    ].request();
  }

  late InAppWebViewController _webViewController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InAppWebView(
      initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse(widget.url)),
      initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
        crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
          javaScriptEnabled: true,
          transparentBackground: true,
        ),
      ),
      onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
        _webViewController = controller;
      },
      androidOnGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt:
          (InAppWebViewController controller, String origin) async {
        await getPermission();
        return GeolocationPermissionShowPromptResponse(
            origin: origin, allow: true, retain: true);
      },
    );
  }
}

"""
```

[image]

Hi all! I am currently trying to handle the error for geolocation denied. I do not like the default error given to me by the inappwebview package and would like to personalize it to match the app layout. How would this be done? Thanks